# Only angles with x-axis is given of the line is given and it extending to infinity how can i determine the number of perellogram formed ??

Tags: geometry

We have given N lines and angles with the x-axis (positive or negative), these lines are not overlapped with each other, how do I find the number of Parallelograms.

example given:-

there are 5 lines and angles with the x-axis is 20,20,-20,- 20,50 and the number of Parallelograms is formed is 1.

How do I determine the number of parallelograms??

screenshot:-[of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Ixu.png)

Comment: You need 2 pairs of parallel lines to make a parallelogram. Two lines are parallel if they have the same slope, i.e., if the angle they make with the x-axis is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelograms arise from two pairs of parallel lines, but the four lines
cannot all be parallel.

So, take a finite number of lines, and arrange them into parallel
classes: $A_1,\ldots,A_k$. That is the lines in $A_i$ are parallel with each
other but not with the lines in $A_j$ for $j\ne i$. Let $|A_i|=a_i$. Then the
number of parallelograms is
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le k}\binom{a_i}2\binom{a_j}2.$$
The typical summand here counts the parallelograms formed by lines in $A_i$
and $A_j$.

In your example, you have $k=2$, $a_1=2$, $a_2=2$ and $a_3=1$.